# Are numpy logical element wise operations broken for pandas 2.0? (np.logical_or)

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I have a code that was working till I update to pandas 2.0, I checked in the changelog and I see that they changed the behavior of logical_or, but it doesn't seem exactly the same thing: https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/pull/37374 so it a is very unexpected error for me.

```
a = pd.DataFrame({"or":[False,True], "a":[True,True], "b":[True, False]})
np.logical_or(a[["a","b"]], a[2*["or"]])
```

Before 2.0 it use to do a element wise "or", now it directly fails  0.o with:

```
ValueError: cannot reindex on an axis with duplicate labels
```

Or if provided with two different labels in the second then is even worst as it doesn't fail but concatenates both in a extremely erratic way.

Is this a known bug on pandas / numpy? or is it intended? Is there any known efficient alternative?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The mentioned error is marked with `# GH#42568` (https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/pull/42568/files).
Actually, the code they've changed is now checking/ensuring for unique labels in `axes["columns"]`. But, even if we change the labels on one of the input dataframes like

```
np.logical_or(a[["a","b"]], a[2*["or"]].set_axis(["d","c"], axis=1))
```

we'd get:

```
      a     b    c    d
0  True  True  NaN  NaN
1  True   NaN  NaN  NaN
```

as it seems like 2 array-like structures are expected to have the **same** column labels (if any) when compared:

```
In [642]: np.logical_or(a[["a","b"]], a[2*["or"]].set_axis(["a","b"], axis=1))
Out[642]: 
      a     b
0  True  True
1  True  True
```

---

A simple workaround is bypass labels check and pass only arrays of values:

```
In [644]: np.logical_or(a[["a","b"]].values, a[2*["or"]].values)
Out[644]: 
array([[ True,  True],
       [ True,  True]])
```

Comment: So is `logical_or` delegating to the `__or__` method pandas frames?

Comment: @hpaulj, it fails earlier on the phase of analyzing a dataframe as array-like structure https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/blob/main/pandas/core/generic.py#L2099

Comment: Thanks for the answer!  so this means it is a bug to correct from pandas/ numpy?

Comment: I reported it as a bug here: https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/issues/54416 cause it seems like a too dangerous behavior that can go unnoticed.

Comment: @ZiurOlpa, it's on pandas side and its strictness of uniqueness of labels